# How do I skip over first bracket in array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am needing to echo out the [number], but as you can see each array has a different parent [], how do I by pass the first one and get go to the [number]?

I basically need to skip over first [], and go to the second on that is [number]

```
Array
(
    [e2a4789d22ff47779722b8d8643894cd] => Array
        (
            [type] => workphone
            [visibility] => public
            [number] => 999-999-9999
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 0
            [preferred] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [1603ebeff250437480f5ce046cac36aa] => Array
        (
            [type] => workphone
            [visibility] => public
            [number] => 999-999-9999
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 0
            [preferred] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [215590630122] => Array
        (
            [type] => workphone
            [visibility] => public
            [number] => 999-999-9999
            [order] => 0
            [preferred] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: `$arr[array_keys($arr)[0]]['number']`, probably

Comment: @MarcB can you post this as a main answer, so I can check as good. This is the one I used and it worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for this is using the `foreach`-loop. Which gives you then the value of the element as variable you tell PHP to assign to.

```
foreach($array as $element) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function to get the first element of `array`.

e.g.

```
$firstElement = reset($arr);
echo $firstElement['number'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the elements in the array(s) using `foreach`.

```
foreach($data as $ele){
    foreach($ele as $id=>$val){
        echo $val['number'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example

```
$array = $yourarray;
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
  echo $v['number'] . '<br>';
}
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The first bracket is just a unique key index foreach subsequent set of data. for example you can get the first set by accessing through the key like this

```
$data['e2a4789d22ff47779722b8d8643894cd']
// will return 
Array
(
  [type] => workphone
  [visibility] => public
  [number] => 999-999-9999
  [id] => 2
  [order] => 0
  [preferred] => 1
)
```

loop through the array to access the data you want,

```
// declare your array if you want to save data in array
$numbers = [];
foreach($data $key =>$value){
    // echo just the number
    echo $value['number'];
    // echo the key and number
    echo $key.' '.$value;
    // or you can build an array 
    $numbers[$key] = $value['number'];
}
print_r($numbers);
```

Hope you find this useful, for more info about arrays take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $id => $element)
{
    // will echo 999-999-9999
    echo $element['number'];
}
```

$array is the whole data structure. We go through as index, that is the $id, which is for example e2a4789d22ff47779722b8d8643894cd and the $element is the element  in the $array[$id] so in the $array[e2a4789d22ff47779722b8d8643894cd]

So the $element is the small array in the large array, and it contains data like:

```
Array
        (
            [type] => workphone
            [visibility] => public
            [number] => 999-999-9999
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 0
            [preferred] => 1
        )
```

So if you need the number attribute, you type $element['number'] and you get it.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable was in an array called $elements then it would look like:

```
$elements['e2a4789d22ff47779722b8d8643894cd']['number']
```